# Sitecore Web API GetRenderingHtml response message

Tags: api, sitecore

I have a requirement of getting HTML output for a component in a page.

I get a response message "Preview is unavailable for the Default rendering." when I try to use GetRenderingHTML Web API.

My API call looks like : 
`http://<HostName>/-/item/v1/-/actions/GetRenderingHtml?database=master&language=en-US&renderingId=<RENDERING_ID>&itemId=<ITEM_ID>`

Comment: Formatted post and corrected speeling

Answer (score 0):

There are couple things you need to consider while using `GetRenderingHtml` action.

1. `GetRenderingHtml` does not return output of a component on a page. The `itemId` parameter is used to find a **datasource** for your component, not a page which uses a component.
2. It only allows `method redering`, `sublayout`, `url rendering`, `xsl rendering`, `webcontrol` and `xmlcontrol` to be rendered.

The fact that your message says `for the Default rendering` means that whatever id you passed as `renderingId`, there is an item in your database with this id and `DisplayName` property set to `Default` and this item is not a rendering listed in point `2`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.Below are some concern, can you clarify me 
1.is that only XLST rendering can be used for GetRenderingHtml ? i can get resp only in XLST & not in View rendering(preview unavailable response).
2.i work in MVC areas &  should my rendering be part of any area. if i do so will it work ?